# How to set up specific python version for virtual environment for python?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyttsx

I am a newbie in python and I am trying to add a new environment for my project which runs fine on my current environment Python 3.7.5
After adding all the dependency I was facing an issue for pyttsx3 package(for python text to speech)
on researching further I found out that this was a problem with python version Python 3.7.6
https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/136

which was the python version for my current virtual environment.
These are the steps that I have followed for install the environment

1. py -m pip install --user virtualenv
2. py -m venv env
3. To activate : .\env\Scripts\activate

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

I want that I can either get Python 3.7.7 or Python 3.7.5(on my current machine) for my virtual environment.

I am using Visual studiocode IDE .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 8):

You can do

```
virtualenv -p python3.7.5 [name]
```

but you need to have `python3.7.5` in your `$PATH` or you will get

```
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.7.5'
```

So, you would better use `conda`

```
conda create --name [name] python=3.7.5
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :)

Comment: If you've got more than one version of python installed, and thinking of creating a virtual environment with a specific version, say you've got python3.8 and python3.9, then you can create a virtual environment like so;
`python3.8 -m venv <your preferred virtual environment name>`